# How to check if 2 listbox have the same items collection?

Tags: vb.net

I load items from a database on lstData then I make a copy of this state on another listbox called lstOriginal using this code

```
lstOriginal.Items.Clear()
    For Each Item In lstData.Items
        lstOriginal.Items.Add(Item)
    Next
```

Then the user is available to make changes, add or delete items on lstData and when the user press UPDATE I need to know if the items collection of lstData and lstOriginal are the same.

I don´t care about what changed, if there's a difference I will update the complete items collection on the data base.

So I need to know if the items collection of lstData and lstOriginal are the same.

The only way I know is make a loop like

```
Dim lstOriginalString as String
lstOriginalString = ""
For Each Item In lstOriginal.Items
        lstOriginalString = lstOriginalString & Item
Next
```

Then another loop for lstData and a simple string compare, but I think there's gonna be a simpler way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
Dim isSame As Boolean = lstData.Items.Count = lstOriginal.Items.Count
If isSame Then
   Dim newItems = lstData.Items.Cast(Of String)()
   Dim originalItems = lstOriginal.Items.Cast(Of String)()
   isSame = Not newItems.Except(originalItems).Any()
End If
```

If you wanted to know if it's even in the same order:

```
isSame = newItems.SequenceEqual(originalItems)
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked really well on my case.